# Invalid location of tag Caution (h2) in Eclipse

Tags: java, html, eclipse

Im new in eclipse for Java EE and i got this problem, this program example was running, but have some warning at h2 and h3 as tag html..
This is my code..

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <font color="green"><h2>Selamat Datang, Tanggal dan Waktu sekarang adalah: </h2></font>
    <font color="red"><h2><%= new java.util.Date() %></h2></font>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help and thankyou.. (sry for my english)

Comment: Uhg. Don't use `<font>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not define H2 Tag inside Font tag.
If required, create a CSS element for H2 tags; or define CSS classes.

Another option is to simply ignore it. It must just be a warning.

Comment: yea u right, im just following some little example from book.. I just move H2 tags before Font tags and it works.. I want to ignore it, but my eyes got annoyed :D